# Как можно менять разные view в одном окне WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

К примеру: есть окно регистрации и окно ввода кредов (наследники Window).  Как можно реализовать поведение подобное использованию `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` для окон? Сейчас я выделил два UserControlа - регистрации и ввода учетных данных, и меняю `Visibility`, используя `VisualStateManager`.
Также читал о возможности использования `ContentPresenter` или `ContentHolder.Content`, но при этом подходе нет возможности анимирования переходов с одного на другой. Есть ли правильный подход?

Comment: А какая анимация вам нужна? Если вы добавите анимацию на смену Visibility на false/true для каждого из view, этого не будет достаточно?

Comment: Я бы не стал заморачиваться с несколькими Window (и их наследниками), учитывая, что это единственный по сути объект, у которого есть Native Handle в WPF. Вариант с подменой UserControl ближе.

Answer (score 1):

Более менее контролируемые переходы между страничками можно сделать используя `Frame` и `Page` внутри него.

Насчет анимации правда не искал, как минимум можно сделать промежуточный `Page` с анимацией.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку Prism от Microsoft, а конкретно - регионы из неё. Всё, что вам нужно будет сделать для активации новой вьюхи - вызвать метод RegisterViewWithRegion у IRegionManager.